# Change button colour with data from database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a button that has to be green when the current time is smaller then `row['end']`. And if the row is smaller then the current time the button has to be red. This is what I tried so far.

**My code that has to check**

```
include '../../../include/dbConnection/dbcon.php';
$sqlTokens = "SELECT `end` FROM hw_token WHERE token_id = '".$token_id."'";
      $resultInfo = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlTokens);

//Show results if > then 0.
if (mysqli_num_rows($resultInfo) > 0) {
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultInfo)) {
      if(time() > $row['end'])
      {
        $color = "background-color: #d9534f;";
      }
      else {
        $color = "background-color: #5cb85c;";
      }
      echo "<button class='ServiceOff btn glyphicon glyphicon-globe' name='on_off' value='".$token_id."' style='".$color." color: #fff;''></button>";
  } else {
    echo "Error";
}
```

**How the rest of my function looks like but more**

```
    echo "<form class='form-horizontal' action='functions/postActions.php' enctype='multipart/form-data' method='POST'>";
      echo '            <div class="form-group">';
      echo '                <label for="inputEditHex" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Company Name:</label>';
      echo '                <div class="col-sm-10">';
      echo '                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="bedrijfsnaam" value="'.getTokenInfo($token_id, 0).'">';
      echo '                </div>';
      echo '             </div>';
      echo '             <div class="form-group">';
      echo '                 <label for="inputEditHertz" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Company Domain:</label>';
      echo '                 <div class="col-sm-10">';
      echo '                     <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Url" value="'.getTokenInfo($token_id, 1).'">';
      echo '                 </div>';
      echo '             </div>';
      echo '             <div class="form-group">';
      echo '                 <label for="inputEditnaam" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Survey:</label>';
      echo '                 <div class="col-sm-10">';
      echo '                     <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Enquete" value="'.getMedia($token_id, 1).'">';
      echo '                 </div>';
      echo '             </div>';
```

My expected result is that the button changes colour if the current time is bigger or smaller then my data in my database. But what actually happens is that I can't go to the page. I don't get any errors because it won't open the file at all.

Comment: is your error display flag is enable?

Comment: @bimalsharma i don't think so, because i don't know what that is

Comment: Try adding this at the top of your php file.
   "ini_set('display_errors', 1);
   ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
   error_reporting(E_ALL);" to display the errors.

Comment: @PSone I don't get an error... because it won't open the file at all. but I tried to execute just a simple query and it wouldn't work either...

Comment: `I don't get any errors because this is a different file then my index.php` doesn't make sense. If you have access to your own files, then you can see and test any file for errors.

Comment: @Rasclatt It works! But the page is a sort of a pop up. And I don't know why but when i had the wrong code it couldn't open the pop up so i couldn't see any errors

Comment: On the pop up page is where you should have put the `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` as suggested earlier. It would have revealed your syntax error on that pop up.

Comment: @Rasclatt hmm I had that in my code. Weird

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your PHP file wont compile since the `while` block isn't closed properly (i.e. mismatch of `{` and `}`).

```php
        $color = "background-color: #5cb85c;";
      }
      echo "<button class='ServiceOff btn glyphicon glyphicon-globe' name='on_off' value='".$token_id."' style='".$color." color: #fff;''></button>";
   } // <-- *** YOU NEED TO ADD THIS ***
} else {
  echo "Error";
}
```

Also, you have an extra `'` at the end of your opening `button` tag which may cause issues with web browsers when rendering the page.